# Publish two web services on the same address

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

I have a simple question about deploying web services. Currently I have two endPoints, see below:

```
Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8000/eCalcWS/eCalc", new eCalc());

Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8001/eCalcWS/eCalc_service", new eCalc_service());
```

Is it possible to have two web services on the same address? How would I do that?

Comment: Why would you want two web servers on the same address? How do you plan on differentiating so you can be sure you get exactly the service you want?

Comment: I just want to publish two different classes on the same address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not the way you want.
The design is that each endpoint is associated with web service implementor.
From [spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr224/index.html):

> The Endpoint class can be used to create and publish Web service
>   endpoints.   An endpoint consists of an object that acts as the Web
>   service implementation (called here implementor) plus some
>   configuration information, e.g. a Binding

and on publish (my emphasis):

> publish(String address, Object implementor)
>   Creates and publishes an Endpoint **for the given implementor**. The binding is chosen by
>   default based on the URL scheme of the provided address (which must be
>   a URL). If a suitable binding if found, the endpoint is created then
>   published as if the Endpoint.publish(String address) method had been
>   called. The created Endpoint is then returned as the value of the
>   method.

I remember I also encounter this problem quite a while back which is really bad as I needed to associate 2-3 different implementations with different URLs and it was impossible (got address already bind error).
The way I got around this if I recall was to create my own dispatcher.
I published an endpoint that accepted web service requests for multiple endpoints and dispatched the request to the corresponding implementation. I worked directly on the SOAP message.
But it was possible for me since the xml messages were really simple and quite few.
For you I would recommend to publish in different endpoints if your web service implementations are non-trivial and have complicated messages and expect a lot of clients as the endpoint really just deploys a *simple* http server under the hood.